Bitcoin SE Twitter account
I'd like to follow the official Bitcoin SE Twitter account to keep up to date with questions here, but it looks like it hasn't been updated since May.
It's got over 1320 followers, so is probably a useful promotional tool for the site.
Is there a server somewhere someone needs to kick to get it auto-tweeting again? ;-)

You're looking at the wrong account. This is the Bitcoin SE Twitter account:
https://twitter.com/StackBitcoin
I don't know what is behind the link you are using. Apparently, it was something started by a moderator in this thread: Promotional Ideas?

Ah great, thanks! I'll let the mod in that post know that they might like to tell people to follow the other account.

Yeah, I was running an unofficial bot until we got our own official one. Now that there's an official account I've killed mine.

You should maybe notify the BitcoinSE followers of the new account. I see that it has far less followers that your old one.

923 followers by now.
